# Xml Unmarshal failing

Tags: go, xml-parsing

i am trying to Unmarshal simple Xml Schema to Struct. appears to be failing if i have `&#031;` found in any of my Xml Node value.

Reading an Xml file leads to runtime error.
Reading an Xml string leads to missing all other

Sample : http://play.golang.org/p/waNn_1NpD1

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

const (
  s = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <feed>
            <product>
                <description>
                 TEST VALUE sdfsdfsdfsdfsd   TEST VALUE sdfsdfsdfsdfsd   TEST VALUE sdfsdfsdfsdfsd   TEST VALUE sdfsdfsdfsdfsd    &#031;
                </description>
                <sku>ABCDD!@#</sku>
            </product>  
       </feed>`
)

type (
    Feed struct {
        XMLName xml.Name `xml:"feed"`
        Product Product  `xml:"product"`
    }

    Product struct {
        XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"product"`
        Description string   `xml:"description"`
        SKU         string   `xml:"sku"`
    }
)

    func main() {
        fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
        b := []byte(s)
        var feed Feed
        xml.Unmarshal(b, &feed)
        fmt.Println(feed.Product.Description)
        fmt.Println(feed.Product.SKU)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Don't ignore your errors

Your input data is invalid.

`xml.Unmarshal` returns an `error` if it fails. Replacing your call with this:

```
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

...shows:

```
XML syntax error on line 6: illegal character code U+001F
```

Removing the `&#031` from your input makes it work.

<kbd>[See it on the Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/7ZD1C0uyLD)</kbd>

Comment: yes that was my question. whats so special with that UTF character. how i parse with that character

Comment: Its [not a valid XML character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML).